# No puedo hacer el Deploy en Render

Tags: backend, deployment, cloud

chicos, ¿cómo están? No estoy pudiendo hacer `deploy` en render no me da un error en específico los logs me traen puro INFO y un solo `warn` que no logro entender. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

```
 2023-02-22 20:55:58.019  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.Backend.Vanessa.VanessaApplication   : Starting VanessaApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_362 on srv-cfqhilpmbjsoemat7kjg-kn-00001-deployment-fcdd8fbdb-wrnlz with PID 1 (/Vanessa-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
Feb 22 05:55:58 PM  2023-02-22 20:55:58.122  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.Backend.Vanessa.VanessaApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Feb 22 05:56:19 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:19.319  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Feb 22 05:56:21 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:21.322  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1797 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
Feb 22 05:56:39 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:39.917  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
Feb 22 05:56:40 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:40.324  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
Feb 22 05:56:40 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:40.324  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.69]
Feb 22 05:56:42 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:42.920  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Feb 22 05:56:42 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:42.921  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 42901 ms
Feb 22 05:56:50 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:50.131  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
Feb 22 05:56:52 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:52.725  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
Feb 22 05:56:59 PM  2023-02-22 20:56:59.425  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Feb 22 05:57:03 PM  2023-02-22 20:57:03.118  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
Feb 22 05:57:14 PM  2023-02-22 20:57:14.099  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
Feb 22 05:57:15 PM  2023-02-22 20:57:15.325  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
Feb 22 05:58:41 PM  2023-02-22 20:58:41.560  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Feb 22 05:58:41 PM  2023-02-22 20:58:41.617  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Feb 22 05:58:57 PM  2023-02-22 20:58:57.117  WARN 1 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
Feb 22 05:59:12 PM  2023-02-22 20:59:12.326  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Feb 22 05:59:12 PM  2023-02-22 20:59:12.623  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.Backend.Vanessa.VanessaApplication   : Started VanessaApplication in 208.705 seconds (JVM running for 220.077)
Feb 22 06:00:55 PM  2023-02-22 21:00:54.943  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Feb 22 06:00:55 PM  2023-02-22 21:00:55.035  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
Feb 22 06:00:56 PM  2023-02-22 21:00:55.928  INFO 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Por favor agrega las tecnologías que estas usando Ej Java, C#, Go, PHP y si usas el framework también.

Comment: Si claro estoy usando spring boot, con java version 8. Mi base la tengo en clever cloud la integre con mysql 8

Comment: Agrega eso a tu pregunta.

Comment: por lo que vi, en otras consultas muchas veces se comenta en el pom.xml La dependencia donde esta declarada el tomcat. Yo estoy teniendo el mismo problema, exactamente igual, si llegas a poder solucionarlo te agradecería que me avises

Comment: Mauricio esta respuesta me funciono:
En el DOCKERFILE; agrega EXPOSE 8080

FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk MAINTAINER MAURIANDER COPY target/SpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar SpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar EXPOSE 8080 ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/SpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

y el archivo application.properties agregar una linea con lo siguiente: server.port= 10000

Answer (score 0):

En el DOCKERFILE; agrega EXPOSE 8080

FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine-jdk
MAINTAINER MAURIANDER
COPY target/SpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar SpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/SpringBoot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

y el archivo application.properties agregar una linea con lo siguiente:
server.port= 10000

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda de verdad.